# NetSuite saved search not showing all authors on the User notes

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches, netsuite-rest-api

I have a NetSuite saved search for User notes that only shows -All-, -Mine- and -My Team- for Authors. It will not show the individual Authors on the User Notes.

[Saved Search Screenshot for Authors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuB03.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ArifWB To show the individual Authors of each User note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have more than 1000 active employee records? If you do, you will not be able to select an individual employee using the Author filter in the filter region.

On the help center page
[Selecting Available Filters for Saved Searches](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N678025.html#Selecting-Available-Filters-for-Saved-Searches)
there is a section "Limitations for filters displayed in the filter region" where the following limitation is noted:

> The maximum number of items contained in a field that can be displayed
> in a dropdown list is 10,000. If the field is an Entity, the maximum
> number of items is 1,000. If the field contains more items than the
> maximum number, the filter appears as an empty field.

Comment: Thanks Colton. I ended up reaching out to NS Support and they confirmed the same thing. We do have over 1000 records.